# How would I call upon a radio button?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I would like to add text to the response of yes/no within the existing radio button response but I am unsure of how to do so. It would be around line 39 in this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pjdicke/zudCf/2/

```
<p>Yes <input type="radio" name="another" value="anotherYes" /></p>
<p>No <input type="radio" name="another" value="anotherNo" /></p>
```

What do I need to add in order to show text based on the yes/no response?

Line 39 in the HTML section is where the code I quoted is from. I would like the answer to that yes/no to have 2 responses based on the answer. For example: Is the sky blue (no) = why don't you think the sky is blue, do you not like the colour blue? (yes) = what did blue ever do to you? But if the answer was = (no) blue is an awesome colour

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "add text to the response of yes/no within the existing radio button response" ?

Comment: There are only 35 lines of javascript in the jsFiddle, and it appears to do exactly what you want it to do. What is the problem here?

Comment: Line 39 in the HTML section is where the code I quoted is from. I would like the answer to that yes/no to have 2 responses based on the answer. For example: Is the sky blue (no) = why don't you think the sky is blue, do you not like the colour blue? (yes) = what did blue ever do to you? But if the answer was = (no) blue is an awesome colour

Answer (score 0):

I fn hate anonymous functions. While they can have a place, it's mostly just lazy programming, imho.

Here's some code that should hopefully be more clear for you to understand.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
    var radioBtns = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]");
    var i, n = radioBtns.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        var btnGroupName = radioBtns[i].getAttribute('name');

        if (btnGroupName == 'yesNo')
            radioBtns[i].addEventListener('change', onRbGroup1Change, false);

        else if (btnGroupName == 'gender')
            radioBtns[i].addEventListener('change', onRbGroup2Change, false);
    }
}
function onRbGroup1Change()
{
    document.getElementById('radioResult').innerHTML = "Value of chosen radio button is: " + this.value;
}
function onRbGroup2Change()
{
    document.getElementById('radioResult2').innerHTML = "Gender of chosen radio button is: " + this.value;
}

</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<label>Yes<input type="radio" name="yesNo" value="afirmative"/></label>
<label>No<input type="radio" name="yesNo" value="negative"/></label>
<div id='radioResult'>You need to select a radio-button first!</div>

<label>Girl<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female"/></label>
<label>Boy<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male"/></label>
<div id='radioResult2'>You need to select a radio-button first!</div>

</body>
</html>
```